# Script for Google sheets (auto email function)

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Google Sheets Script

I need to generate an auto email reply when Column "A" is marked "Completed".  The email address to send this to is in Column "I" and subject of the email needs to be data in Column "H" while the body of the email will be generic for all emails sent.  This is all specific to each Row.

I have multiple scripts running, for hiding rows etc, but nothing this complex.

All data is sent in to spreadsheet from Google Forms, and will need to encompass all rows

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's the specific issue in your implementation that you are having? We aren't here to write everything for you, you need to attempt something. Review the Apps Script Spreadsheet Service reference for code samples and class methods.

Answer (score 1):

I created a script for something similar to this, except it runs off of check boxes. You could easily edit this code to have the email recipient variable to point to a value in a column by adding a .getdisplayvalue

How I used it is basically just as a script trigger, so I wouldn't have it replace the "progress" column you have, but to add a column for them to check when they're done editing the row.

*Side Note: This script purposefully sets the check box back to default after clicking "yes I want to send the email" on the alert, otherwise the script would continuously run.*

Without seeing your Google Sheet or current code/this code inserted, I wouldn't be able to help you implement at all. Let me know if this helps.

```js
/*

 A function to:
 
* After clicking a checkbox, auto prompt a yes/no box
* Upon "yes", copies that row from the source sheet to a destination sheet
* send an e-mail based on that new row's data
 
 I reccomend protecting the response sheet and hiding it, as well as protecting the check box column to give edit access to only those you want to be able to send e-mails.
 
 NOTES:
 
 *It is important that the headers on your source sheet match your destination sheet.

* You have to run the script from the editor first to accept permissions for the emailapp and driveapp

* you need to set up a project trigger (edit/current project triggers) for the source sheet, on spreadsheet, on edit.

*The email will come from the owner of the google sheet and owner of the script project. (the person who reviews and accepts permissions)
 MAKE SURE you are the owner of the sheet, that you are putting the code into the editor, and that you're okay with the e-mail coming from and replying to your email address.


*/


function EmailNotification(e) {

var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Assets'); //source sheet
var columnb = sheet.getRange('B:B'); //Column with check boxes
var columnbvalue = columnb.getValues();
var notifysheet = ss.getSheetByName('Responses'); //destination sheet
var data = [];
var rownum =[];

//Condition check in B:B (or check box column); If true copy the same row to data array

for (i=0; i<columnbvalue.length;i++) {

if (columnbvalue[i] == 'true') {

var columnb2 = sheet.getRange('B2:B');
columnb2.setValue('false');

// What you want to say in the pop up alert

var response = ui.alert('Hold Up!\n Are you sure you want to send an email to finance for this asset change?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
if (response == ui.Button.YES) {

data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,20).getValues());

//Copy matched ROW numbers to rownum

rownum.push(i);

//Copy data array to destination sheet


notifysheet.getRange(notifysheet.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);

var activeRow = notifysheet.getLastRow();
var assetname = notifysheet.getRange(activeRow, 1).getDisplayValue(); // The number is the column number in the destination "responses" sheet that you want to include in the email
var owner = notifysheet.getRange(activeRow, 3).getDisplayValue();
var serial = notifysheet.getRange(activeRow, 9).getDisplayValue();
var podate = notifysheet.getRange(activeRow, 6).getDisplayValue();

var email = 'theiremail@gmail.com' //The email address in which you want to send the email notification to
var subject = 'Asset has changed department ownership!'

//Body of the email message, using HTML and the variables from above

var message =
'<br><br><div style="margin-left:40px;">Heads Up!</div>'
+'<br><br><div style="margin-left:40px;">An asset has changed department ownership.</div>'
+'<br><br><div style="margin-left:40px;"><h3 style="text-decoration: underline;">Asset Name:'+ assetname +'</h3></div>'
+'<div style="margin-left:40px;">New Departmet Owner: '+ owner +'</div><br>'
+'<div style="margin-left:40px;">Serial: '+ serial +'</div>'
+'<div style="margin-left:40px;">Purchase Date: '+ podate +'</div>'
+ '<br><br><div style="margin-left:40px;">ヽ(⌐■_■)ノ♪♬</div>';

MailApp.sendEmail(
email,
subject,
"",
{
htmlBody: message,
name: 'Sadie Stevens', //The name you want to email coming from. This will be in bold, while your e-mail address will be small in italics
});

}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this:

```
function EmailNotification(e) {
  var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName('Assets');
  var columnb=sheet.getRange(1,2,sheet.getLastRow());
  var columnbvalue=columnb.getValues();
  var notifysheet=ss.getSheetByName('Responses');
  var data=[];
  var rownum=[];
  for (var i=0;i<columnbvalue.length;i++) {
    if (columnbvalue[i] == 'true') {
      var columnb2=sheet.getRange(2,2,sheet.getLastRow()-1);
      columnb2.setValue('false');      
      var response=ui.alert('Hold Up!\n Are you sure you want to send an email to finance for this asset change?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
      if (response==ui.Button.YES) {
        data.push(sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,20).getValues());
        rownum.push(i);
        notifysheet.getRange(notifysheet.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
        var activeRow=notifysheet.getLastRow();
        var assetname=notifysheet.getRange(activeRow, 1).getDisplayValue(); // The number is the column number in the destination "responses" sheet that you want to include in the email
        var owner=notifysheet.getRange(activeRow, 3).getDisplayValue();
        var serial=notifysheet.getRange(activeRow, 9).getDisplayValue();
        var podate=notifysheet.getRange(activeRow, 6).getDisplayValue();
        var email='theiremail@gmail.com' //The email address in which you want to send the email notification to
        var subject='Asset has changed department ownership!'
        var message =
            '<br><br><div style="margin-left:40px;">Heads Up!</div>'
        +'<br><br><div style="margin-left:40px;">An asset has changed department ownership.</div>'
        +'<br><br><div style="margin-left:40px;"><h3 style="text-decoration: underline;">Asset Name:'+ assetname +'</h3></div>'
        +'<div style="margin-left:40px;">New Departmet Owner: '+ owner +'</div><br>'
        +'<div style="margin-left:40px;">Serial: '+ serial +'</div>'
        +'<div style="margin-left:40px;">Purchase Date: '+ podate +'</div>'
        + '<br><br><div style="margin-left:40px;">ヽ(⌐■_■)ノ♪♬</div>';
        
        MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,"",{htmlBody: message,name: 'Sadie Stevens'});
        
      }
    }
  }
}
```