# Auto Send Email When Checkbox is Checked - Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I tried the script from [Auto Email Function for Google Sheets Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63696693/auto-email-function-for-google-sheets-mobile) and it worked the first time. When I tried to change the variables, it does not automatically send the email, unless I run the script again, it would then update the response sheet and then clears the checkbox. Please help me with this. Kindly see my code below.

```
 function EmailNotification(e) {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Course_AutoEmail'); //source sheet
     var columnb = sheet.getRange('I:I'); //Column with check boxes
     var columnbvalue = columnb.getValues();
     var notifysheet = ss.getSheetByName('Responses'); //destination sheet
     var data = [];
     var rownum = [];

     //Condition check in B:B (or check box column); If true copy the same row to data array

     for (let i = 0; i < columnbvalue.length; i++) {
       if (columnbvalue[i][0] === true) {
     
         var columnb2 = sheet.getRange('I747:I'); //row started in row 747
         columnb2.setValue('false');
         data.push.apply(data, sheet.getRange(i + 1, 1, 1, 20).getValues());

      //Copy matched ROW numbers to rownum

         rownum.push(i);

      //Copy data array to destination sheet

         notifysheet.getRange(notifysheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);

         var activeRow = notifysheet.getLastRow();
         var name = notifysheet.getRange(activeRow, 1).getDisplayValue(); // The number is the column number in the destination "responses" sheet that you want to include in the email
         var employeeID = notifysheet.getRange(activeRow, 2).getDisplayValue();
         var position = notifysheet.getRange(activeRow, 3).getDisplayValue();
         var team = notifysheet.getRange(activeRow, 4).getDisplayValue();
         var date = notifysheet.getRange(activeRow, 10).getDisplayValue();
         var rec1 = notifysheet.getRange(activeRow, 19).getDisplayValue();
         var rec2 = notifysheet.getRange(activeRow, 20).getDisplayValue();
         var email = rec1 + "," + rec2;
         var subject = name + ': 201 Completion';
      //Body of the email message, using HTML and the variables from above

         var message =
           '<br><div style="margin-left:10px;">Hi, </div>' +
           '<br><div style="margin-left:10px;">Good day!</div>' +
           '<br><div style="margin-left:10px;"><b>' + name + '</b> has completed the course. </div>' +
        
           '<br><div style="margin-left:20px;"><h3 style="text-decoration: underline; color: #f36f21">Employee Details: </h3></div>' +
           '<div style="margin-left:25px;">Name: <b>' +
           name +
           '</b></div>' +
           '<div style="margin-left:25px;">Position: <b>' +
        position +
           '</b></div>' +
           '<div style="margin-left:25px;">Team: <b>' +
        team +
           '</b></div>' +
           '<div style="margin-left:25px;">Completion Date: <b>' +
        date +
           '</b></div>' +
           '<br><br><div style="margin-left:10px;">Let me know if you have any questions. </div>' +
           '<br><div style="margin-left:10px;">Thanks! </div>';

         MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, '', {
           htmlBody: message,
           name: 'Updates', 
         });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: trigger:

EmailNotification > From spreadsheet > On edit

Comment: Do you have the trigger set up on simple or installable `onEdit` trigger? After perfoming an edit in the sheet, go from the Apps Script editor to `View->Executions` and see either your funciton has been triggered and if you it gave you any error.

Answer (score 1):

I read your code.
if you don't want your checked checkbox unchecked in spreadsheet.
so you have to remove `columnb2.setValue('false');` line of code.
this line is made checkbox unchecked.
solution of other problems : http://one7techlab.com

Comment: I tried that but my problem is it doesn't automatically send an email nor update the response sheet. I have to re-run the apps script to send the email of the checked rows.

Comment: you have to set a time based trigger on that function.

Comment: you can set that trigger in every 10 minute if you are available or not in your sheet.